# display most popular tags in two columns

Tags: php, functions, widgets, tags, sidebar

I have a section in my sidebar where I'd like to display my most popular tags in two columns. I found [this post](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/tags/show-most-used-tags-in-list/) from WPSnipp that details how to narrow your list down to only the most popular, however I'm wondering how I can arrange them to appear in two columns - 10 on the left, and 10 on the right in alphabetical order.

Here's what I'm using:
functions.php

```
<?php
function top_tags() {
        $tags = get_tags();
        if (empty($tags))
                return;
        $counts = $tag_links = array();
        foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
                $counts[$tag->name] = $tag->count;
                $tag_links[$tag->name] = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
        }
        asort($counts);
        $counts = array_reverse( $counts, true );
        $i = 0;
        foreach ( $counts as $tag => $count ) {
                $i++;
                $tag_link = clean_url($tag_links[$tag]);
                $tag = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', wp_specialchars( $tag ));
                if($i < 11){
                        print "<li><a href=\"$tag_link\">$tag ($count)</a></li>";
                }
        }
}
?>
```

sidebar-r.php

```
<h2 class="widgettitle">#HASHTAG</h2>
        <? $tags = top_tags();
        $tags_count = count($tags);
        $number = ceil($tags_count / 2);
        $args = array('number' => $number);
        $tagsleft = get_tags($args);
        $args = array('number' => $number, 'offset' => $number);
        $tagsright = get_tags($args);

        $html = '<ul class="catleft">';
            foreach ($tagsleft as $tag){
                $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);

                $html .= "<li><a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
                $html .= "{$tag->name}</a></li>";
            }
            $html .= '</ul>';

            $html .= '<ul class="catright">';
            foreach ($tagsright as $tag){
                $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);

                $html .= "<li><a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
                $html .= "{$tag->name}</a></li>";
            }
            $html .= '</ul>';
            echo $html;
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you are doing it so complicated.

I would rather do a classic query and then through css it made into 2-column.

```
function top_tags() {
    $tags = get_the_tags();

        if($tags)
        {
             $output = '<h4>Top tags</h4> <ul class="top_tags">';
             foreach($tags as $tag)
                   $output .= '<li><a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'" title="'.$tag->name.'">'.$tag->name.'</a></li>';

             $output .= '</ul>';

             echo $output;
         }
}
```

and your css

```
.top_tags li {display:block; float:left; width:50%; clear:right;}
```

Comment: Works perfectly (ignore my previous content, found the problem). Thanks again for your help.