# How To get a list of popular tags by post views?

Tags: tags

I am searching for a code, not a plugin, that will allow me to display the most popular tags based on post views for that day.

Someone asked this same question but they asked about a plugin, my points aren't high enough for me to comment and ask for a code, so I have to waste space and the same question :(

Comment: Hmm it sounds like you have two steps in this, since it's not based on just getting the tags used most by posts (which is what the tag cloud uses) - but instead it's checking for popular posts, and then grabbing the tags from those popular posts. So the tags themselves are not "popular" but the posts themselves just happen to have those tags. Maybe these two links will help? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120285/display-most-popular-tags-in-two-columns and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48557/display-list-of-most-used-tags-in-the-last-30-days

Answer (score 0):

First thing we need to do is create a function that will detect post views count and store it as a custom field for each post. To do this, paste the following codes in your theme’s functions.php

```
> function wpb_set_post_views($postID) {
>     $count_key = 'wpb_post_views_count';
>     $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
>     if($count==''){
>         $count = 0;
>         delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
>         add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
>     }else{
>         $count++;
>         update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
>     } } //To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Now that you have this function in place, we need to call this function on the single post pages. This way the function knows exactly which post gets the credit for the views. To do this, you would need to paste the following code inside your single post loop:

```
wpb_set_post_views(get_the_ID());
```